# Limiting the amount of authors in the bibliography made with natbib

Tags: natbib

I am using `natbib` to manage my references, and I have a problem: I want to limit the number of authors displayed in the bibliography to 5 authors 'et al', but my reference list always displays all author names of an article.

The options I have for `natbib` are as follows:

```
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
```

With `biblatex` I could use:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=5]{biblatex}
```

but seems it is not compatible with `natbib`.

Is there a similar option for `natlib`?
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT1
I am using `Overleaf`, so I don't think I can change the hardcoded values. Bibliography stile is `\bibliographystyle{francaissc}`

EDIT2

I saw `natbib`: how to display partial authors in reference but I don't like very much thesolution (at the end remove manually the authors). It would be a pain as there are hundreds of citations in my `bibtex` file, and as I tis not determined how much authors I will have to let at the end.

Any idea how to do it?

EDIT3 My message was marked as a possible duplicate of  [natbib: how to display partial authors in reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/natbib-how-to-display-partial-authors-in-reference) but there is NO SOLUTION provided inside this message.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think there is a general `natbib` option. It will depend on the `.bst`/`\bibligraphystyle` you use. Normally the cut-off values are hard-coded there.

Comment: See also this very similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127705/35864. But there are also some styles that allow you to control the number of names displayed via an interface: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184948/35864. We need to know what style you use to be able to help in more detail.

Comment: Please do reveal which bibliography style you employ. (`natbib` is primarily a citation management package. It's not involved in the details of how bib entries are formatted (incl truncation decisions for long author lists).

Comment: I am using overleaf, so i don't think I can change the hardcoded values. 

Bibliography stile is \bibliographystyle{francaissc}

Comment: In the referenced question there were two answers. The accepted one does not require you to manually remove the authors, so I think it perfectly solves your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [natbib: how to display partial authors in reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/natbib-how-to-display-partial-authors-in-reference)

Comment: if I use 
\usepackage{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{maxauthors = 5}
As suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184948/allow-more-authors-before-replacement-by-et-al-with-natbib-achemso it don't work because this package is not on overleaf. Is there any way to put this option direcly in natbib, since I want to have the same limit for all the bibliography ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend changing the style file like in the aswer of [natbib: how to display partial authors in reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/natbib-how-to-display-partial-authors-in-reference), but if you only want to change your TeX file, you can use the following to print `et collab` after five authors, if there are more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Batty:2007,
  author    = {Michael Batty and Max Musti and Someone Else and Another One and Still exists and Who Else},
title     = {Cities and Complexity},
publisher = {MIT Press},
year      = 2007}
@Book{atty:2007,
author    = {Michael Atty and Max Musti and Someone Else and Another One},
title     = {Cities and Complexity},
publisher = {MIT Press},
year      = 2007}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}
  \let\oldbibitem\bibitem
  \let\oldtextsc\textsc
  \def\oldbbland{et}
  \newcounter{authorcount}
  \def\bibitem[##1]##2{%
    \let\textsc\oldtextsc
    \let\bbland\oldbbland
    \oldbibitem[##1]{##2}%
    \let\textsc\mytextsc%
    \let\bbland\mybbland
    \setcounter{authorcount}{0}
  }
  \def\mybbland{\setcounter{authorcount}{0}\oldbbland}
  \def\dropetal##1.{ \bbletal}
  \def\mytextsc##1{%
    \oldtextsc{##1}%
    \stepcounter{authorcount}%
    \ifnum\value{authorcount}=5\relax%
      \expandafter\dropetal%
    \fi%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

This a citation \cite{Batty:2007}\ and \cite{atty:2007}

\bibliographystyle{francaissc}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]